# How do I view information about a package in nix?

Tags: nix

How do I get more details about a nix package, e.g. to verify that it actually is what I think it is.

In Debian, I would use `apt-cache show`; but how do I get similar information for nix? A command to show the derivation for an arbitrary package would be good enough, since I can probably use the `src` line to find the website hosting the project.

Comment: There is a site for Nix [packages](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html) and one for NixOS [options](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass the `--description` flag to `nix-env -qa` ("query available") for a brief summary, or pass `--json` (or `--xml --meta`) for more verbose output, with similar content to that available on Debian; though you'll probably also need something that can wrangle those forms to human readable

```
# nix-env -qa --description neovim
neovim-0.2.0  Vim text editor fork focused on extensibility and agility
# nix-env -qa --json neovim
{"nixos.neovim":{"name":"neovim-0.2.0","system":"x86_64-linux","meta":{"descriptio...
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why `--description` is not the default? I made an edit to emphasize the needed options, since I didn't realize `nix-env -qa` had an alternate output.

Comment: note: not all packages have descriptions